# Deploying jenkins war file using java command

Tags: java, jenkins, war

I am trying to deploy a jenkins war file. I executed the following command

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

Below is the log file.

> PS C:\Sites> java -jar jenkins.war Running from: C:\Sites\jenkins.war
>   webroot: $user.home/.jenkins Sep 03, 2014 6:09:15 PM winstone.Logger
>   logInternal INFO: Beginning extraction from war file Sep 03, 2014
>   6:09:28 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO:
>   jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT Sep 03, 2014 6:09:35 PM
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info INFO: NO JSP Support for ,
>   did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet Jenkins home
>   directory: C:\Users\Mathew.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
>   Sep 03, 2014 6:09:46 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
>   INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 Sep 03, 2014 6:09:46
>   PM winstone.Logger logInternal INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0
>   running: controlPort=disabled Sep 03, 2014 6:09:46 PM
>   jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Started initialization
>   Sep 03, 2014 6:10:26 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO:
>   Listed all plugins Sep 03, 2014 6:10:26 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1
>   onAttained INFO: Prepared all plugins Sep 03, 2014 6:10:26 PM
>   jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Started all plugins Sep
>   03, 2014 6:10:26 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO:
>   Augmented all extensions Sep 03, 2014 6:10:26 PM
>   jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Loaded all jobs Sep 03,
>   2014 6:10:42 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start INFO:
>   Started SSHD at port 55062 Sep 03, 2014 6:10:45 PM
>   jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained INFO: Completed initialization
>   Sep 03, 2014 6:10:45 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run INFO: Jenkins is fully
>   up and running Sep 03, 2014 6:11:48 PM
>   hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load INFO: Obtained the
>   updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller Sep 03, 2014
>   6:11:51 PM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load INFO:
>   Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Ant.AntInstaller Sep
>   03, 2014 6:11:52 PM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
>   INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller Sep
>   03, 2014 6:12:11 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData INFO: Obtained
>   the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default

1. Can anyone tell me what does the command `java-jar jenkins.war` do?
2. WHere did it deploy my war file?
3. Which web server does it use and how does localhost:8080 point to jenkins application?

Answer (score 2):

Q. Can anyone tell me what does the command java -jar jenkins.war do?

`java -jar` expects a jar file name, in this case, jenkins.war.

An executable Java program can be packaged in a JAR file, along with any libraries the program uses. Executable JAR files have the manifest specifying the entry point class with Main-Class: myPrograms.MyClass and an explicit Class-Path (and the -cp argument is ignored). Some operating systems can run these directly when clicked. The typical invocation is "java -jar foo.jar" from a command line

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Q. Where did it deploy my war file?

In case it is a RHEL/CentOS installation, your war is deployed at `/var/lib/jenkins`

You can find out the location by reading the file /etc/init.d/jenkins. You will find a variable named `JENKINS_CONFIG`

```
JENKINS_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

Q. Which web server does it use and how does localhost:8080 point to jenkins application?

In case it is a RHEL/CentOS installation, you will generally find the file here: `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`. In this file, you define port on which Jenkins runs.

Answer (score 2):

1) It executes the java arvhive jenkins.war (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)

2) From the output you posted yourself:

```
Running from: C:\Sites\jenkins.war webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
```

the `user.home` variable may refer to your `~` directory on Linux, or your Document and Settings on windows. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

3) From the output you posted yourself:

`jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080`

See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/. This is a web server that register a listener on port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

it uses the Manifest.mf inside, if you open the war, you would understand how it runs

The Main class uses winstone http://winstone.sourceforge.net/

I would recommend to use glassfish, jetty or tomcat - for better control on configuration

there is a bug open for that
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18366

Also see various container notes
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Containers